# Calling external assembly

Tags: nlua

i am referring to "SomeClass" on the NLua home page.
Let#s assume that this has been compiled into assembly "SomeClass".

When i want to use it in Lua, i should be abler to refer to it using:

import ('SomeClass', 'SomeClass') 
myclass=SomeClass()   -- to call the constructor
func1=myclass:Func1() -- to call Func1

Correct?
At leat this is how in the samples the standard .Net Assemblies are used.
I am however always failing. "Someclass" is always nil.

Unfortunately the samples always refer to using lua with "DoString" inside the C# object.
But i'd like to use that from within Nlua.exe.

Any hint?

thanks,

Helmut

EDIT: Ok, i am a bit further. Using Debug, i found out that the import is loading my assembly correctly.
But when i want to get an instance of my assembly, i get an error:

[image]

Comment: Is this a Managed Class? Oh boy, I know how to do it from unmanaged C/CPP but didn't even realize you could do it from LUA.

Comment: Yes, it is managed code. with NLua you could do it.

Answer (score 0):

Had an error in the Namespace. One character was lower case as opposed to be uppercase.
Fixed it and it is ok now.